# How to break an array and use part of it with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am new to this so your help is much needed. I have a CSV file and I need to modify the last column of this CSV. What I did is separated the columns in array using this code below.

```
<?php
function readCSV($csvFile){

    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile,"r");

    while (!feof($file_handle)) {

        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }

fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;

}



$csvFile = 'testslash.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);

print_r($csv);

?>
```

This is the output i am getting which is fine .. what i want  to end up with ex: array 0,2 and array 1,2. i tried array slice but with no avail. any other options?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC
            [1] => XXX
            [2] => 972 54 120000 / 129999
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DEF
            [1] => XXX
            [2] => 972 52 1100180 / 9
        )

)
```

Comment: tried `foreach` loop?

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Use `array_slice()` with the array returned by `fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);` (i.e. process the data as soon as it's possible)

Comment: By using foreach($array as $key=>$value) and then you can use $value[0],$value[1],$value[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying you want only a specific part of the subarrays.
This is easily done using a foreach loop and a new array.

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($cvs as $row)
{
    $resultArray[] = $row[2]; //if you dont care about the index of the array
    $resultArray[$row[0]] = $row[2]; //if you want to speficy the index as the value of e.g. the first entry of the subarray;
}
```